# Relaunch iOS app without user interface when application in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

how to relaunch iOS app without user interface when application in background?

I know notification but in any notification user must click alert view button to relaunch or open app.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this.
User must involve for doing this.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, as everyone else has said. You can do background stuff though, but this is limited in various ways:

> For iOS apps, it is crucial to know whether your app is running in the
>   foreground or the background. Because system resources are more
>   limited on iOS devices, an app must behave differently in the
>   background than in the foreground. The operating system also limits
>   what your app can do in the background in order to improve battery
>   life and to improve the user’s experience with the foreground app. The
>   operating system notifies your app whenever it moves between the
>   foreground and background. These notifications are your chance to
>   modify your app’s behavior.

-- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: then how is it possible in whatsapp when someone call us ?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to launch your app programmatically, without user interaction ? I do not think there's a way to do it, due to iOS limitation, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in general case on stock device.
It depends what you mean by "user interaction".
I had a case for one app(smth like server) where user can do anything with device but do not able to touch screen, because device was placed in special box.
I found a way to use Siri.
I enabled option "Hey, Siri" and user can re/launch app with voice commands.